# How to get the concrete update of an entity inside the controller in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

please I'm completely stuck please help me.

I have a OneToMany relation between two entities; course and seance. The creation's and edition's forms of the course and its related seances are rendered in the same page using the technique of embedded forms.
Anyway, what I want is that when the admin of the webapp edits some of the course details ( hours number, title .. ) or the related seances details ( date or place ) I want to notify the students whom are subscribed to that course about the update. I managed to do this, telling the user : "the course ... is updated". But I want the concrete update, for example to tell the user :"the admin changed the date of the next seance to ../../....".

I hope you understand me. I can't even think of a way to get the real update inside the editAction. 
Any help would be appreciated. This is editAction of my controller:

```
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $course = $em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Course')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new CourseType(), $course);
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
      $em->flush();

// this StudentCourse is the association entity between student and course which holds extra fields ( date registration , etc ..)

   $studentcourse = $em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:StudentCourse')->findBy(array('course' => $course));

// this is the service I created to notify a list of users 

   $notificateur=$this->get('Notificateur');
   $repository2=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Student');
      foreach ($studentcourse as $sc)
        { $user=$sc->getStudent()->getId();
        $student=$repository2->findBy(array('id' => $user));
        $notificateur->notifier('the course '.$course->getTitle().' is updated',$student);
        }

  return new Response('OK'); }

return $this->render('OCUserBundle:Course:course.html.twig', array(
  'form'   => $form->createView(),
  'course' => $course
));
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. Can't you return a boolean from `$notificateur->notifier` telling if the course was updated, if you need that in `editAction`?

Comment: @KonstantinPereyaslov : by answering this question you will understand what I mean: How to tell the subscribed user that the course title is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a doctrine listener:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html

- catch which Seance is being updated in `preUpdate`
- send notifications in `postFlush`

The code would look like (not tested):

```
class SceanceUpdateListener
{
    private $notifier;

    public function __construct(Your\Notifier\NotifierClass $notifier)
    {
        $this->notifier = $notifier;
        $this->updatedSceances = [];
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof Sceance) {
            $this->updatedSceances[] = $entity;
        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (count($this->updatedSceances) === 0) {
            return;
        }
        $studentRepository = $args->getEntityManager()->getRepository('OCUserBundle:Student');
        foreach ($this->updatedSceances as $sceance) {
            $users = $studentRepository->getUsersForSceance($sceance);
            $this->notifier->doStuff($users, $sceance);
        }
    }
}
```

and the listener definition:

```
<service id="listener_name" class="Your\Listener\Class">
    <argument type="service" id="Notificateur" />
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="preUpdate" />
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="postFlush" />
</service>
```

---

## update

To know what has changed in your entity you could use the `getEntityChangeSet` method of the `PreUpdateEventArgs` you receive in the `preUpdate` event.

The `PreUpdateEventArgs::getEntityChangeSet` will return an array of the properties that have changed. For each property you will have access to the old value and the new value.

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof Sceance) {
        $changeSet = $args->getEntityChangeSet();
        // do something with the changeSet
        $this->updatedSceances[] = $entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked the idea. But this doesn't answer my question, my goal is not  to catch which object is updated, I will explain it plain English: I want something like compare the course and its related seances and return the difference. Do you understand me better now.?!

Comment: Most accurate answer I found so far. Gonna test this and see what happens. Cheers